# Perl regex find and replace

Tags: regex, perl, replace, substitution

I'm new to perl and I'm trying to figure out a find and replace. I have a large csv file (actually semi-colon separated). Some of the numbers (int and decimals) in the file have a negative symbol after the number. I need to move the negative sign to before the number.

E.g: Change

```
ABC;10.00-;XYZ
```

to

```
ABC;-10.00;XYZ
```

I'm not sure how to do this in perl. Can someone please help?

Regards,
Anand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not dabble around in a large csv file with regexes, unless I was very sure about my data and the regex. Using a CSV module seems to me to be the safest way.

This script will take input files as arguments, and write the corrected files with a `.new` extension.

If you notice undesired changes in your output file, you can try to un-comment the `keep_meta_info` line.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use Text::CSV;

my $out_ext = ".new";
my $csv = Text::CSV->new( { 
        sep_char => ";",
        #   keep_meta_info => 1,
        binary => 1,
        eol => $/,
    } ) or die "" . Text::CSV->error_diag();

for my $arg (@ARGV) {
    open my $input, '<', $arg;
    open my $output, '>', $arg . $out_ext;
    while (my $row = $csv->getline($input)) {
        for (@$row) {
            s/([0-9\.]+)\-$/-$1/;
        }
        $csv->print($output, $row);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you don't have to worry about quoteing or escaping in your delimited file. I'll read from standard in/out, change to appropriate files if req'd

```
while( my $line = <STDIN> )
{
    chop( $line );
    my @rec = split( ';', $line );
    map( s/^(\d*\.?\d+)\-$/-$1/, @rec );
    print join(';',@rec) . "\n";
}
```

If you do have to worry about escaping and quoting, then use [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/~hmbrand/Text-CSV_XS-0.82/CSV_XS.pm) instead of the `<STDIN>`, `split`, and `join` oprerations

Comment: `chop` should probably be `chomp`. You might wish to be careful about using `split` on a csv file, as it can cause unwanted changes to the file. From [perldoc perlfunc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) : `By default, empty leading fields are preserved, and empty trailing ones are deleted.`

Answer (score 0):

In general, the replace command is `s/old/new/flags`:

```
s/(           # start a capture group
    \d+       # first part of the number
    (\.\d+)?  # possibly a decimal dot and the fractional part
  )-          # end capture group, match the minus sign
 /-$1/gx      # move minus to the front
```

The `g` flag means “global” (replace all occurences), and `x` is “extended legibility” (allows whitespace and comments in the pattern). You have to test the expression on your data to see what corner cases you might have missed, it usually takes a few iterations to get the right one. Samples:

```
$ echo "10.5-;10-;0-;a-" | perl -pe 's/(\d+(\.\d+)?)-/-$1/g'
-10.5;-10;-0;a-
```

See also [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) (search for “replacement” to jump to the right section).

Comment: Won't this mess up dates? E.g. `2011-01-01` would be turned into `-2011-0101`.

Comment: Yes, that's quite possible. That's why I said I always try the pattern on the real data first to see what I might have missed. Doing several iterations with simple regex replacement is IMO often easier than going for a more general solution.

Comment: Unless it is a large file, like the OP said, in which case you need to be rather careful. You're right though, in that we can't tweak the code as well as the OP himself can.

Comment: Adding a lookahead with semi-colons at the start and end might be prudent, for example.

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea. "Large" file does not really imply "complex". It might be the case that the file is a dump from some measurement or whatever and the format is really simple, only there's a lot of the data. But I think we understand each other, the rest is on the poster to figure out.